# User input: selecting two lines

Tags: autolisp

I am a beginer to use/write autocad lisp.
Below is the code I found on Internet. As a beginer I want to modify it and instead of selecting (single line) line1 and line2, I want to do multiple selection of lines (select two lines). Any idea?

```
;------------------------------------------------------------------------
;- Command: midpts_line ()
;-
;- Draws a line between the midpoints of two lines.
;-
;- Copyright 2008 Jeff Winship. All rights Reserved.
;----------------------------------------------------------------5/3/2008
(defun c:midpts_line ()
  ;-- Select the lines
  (setq line1 (car (entsel "\nSelect the first line: ")))
  (setq line2 (car (entsel "\nSelect the second line: ")))

  ;-- Get the endpoints of the first selected line
  (setq pt1 (cdr (assoc 10 (entget line1))))
  (setq pt2 (cdr (assoc 11 (entget line1))))

  ;-- Get the endpoints of the second selected line
  (setq pt3 (cdr (assoc 10 (entget line2))))
  (setq pt4 (cdr (assoc 11 (entget line2))))

  ;-- Find the midpoints of the lines
  (setq mid1 (midpt pt1 pt2))
  (setq mid2 (midpt pt3 pt4))

  ;-- Draw the line
  (command "line" mid1 mid2 "")

)



;------------------------------------------------------------------------
;-  Function: midpt ( p1 p2 )
;-    Arguments: p1 is the starting point of the line
;-               p2 is the ending point of the line
;-
;-    Returns the midpoint of a line given two points.
;-
;- Copyright 2008 Jeff Winship. All rights Reserved.
;----------------------------------------------------------------5/3/2008
(defun midpt (p1 p2 / Xavg Yavg Zavg)

  ;-Calculate the X, Y and Z averages
  (setq Xavg (/(+ (car p1) (car p2))2.0))
  (setq Yavg (/(+ (cadr p1) (cadr p2))2.0))
  (setq Zavg (/(+ (caddr p1) (caddr p2))2.0))

  ;-Return the midpoint as a list
  (list Xavg Yavg Zavg)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`entsel` allows to select only one entity. If You want multiple selection, You should use **ssget**.

Sample code:

```
(setq sset(vl-catch-all-apply 'ssget (list )))
(if (not(vl-catch-all-error-p sset))
  (progn
    (setq i 0)
    (repeat (sslength sset)
        (setq item (ssname sset i))
        (print (entget item) )
        (setq i (1+ i))
    );repeat
  ) ; progn
) ;if
```

SSget is very usefull. You can ask User to select entities, You can also limit selection for user, for example he will be able to select only lines, or only blocks. You can also select entities by defined criteria like layer, color and so one, without any user action.

Answer (score 0):

The previous reply doesn't include the property filter set within (list ) after the 'ssget statement.  If you need to filter out everything except for LINE entities, you'll need to include a filter set.